# tramp/scpc vim buffer randomly appearing

Tags: emacs

Sometimes and apparently out of the blue, I get a new buffer called `*tramp/scpc Vim*` on Emacs. All it says is this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname Vim: Name or service not known
```

Any idea on how I accidentally create it? It happens quite a few times a day and I don't use Vim, only Emacs.

Comment: `(setq debug-on-error t)` should cause a `*Backtrace*` buffer to appear when this happens. With any luck, the trace will pinpoint the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try `C-x C-f /Vim:foo RET` and you will get the behavior you describe.

I.e., you are trying to visit a file whose name starts with `/Vim:` - and `tramp` kicks in thinking that you are trying to visit a file on host `Vim`.

The way to debug this problem is

```
(debug-on-entry 'tramp-error)
```

and the next time this happens you will get the `*Backtrace*` buffer where you will see where tramp is being called from.

Another thing you might want to try is `M-x apropos-value RET /Vim: RET` which will show you all the variables whose value matches `/Vim:`.

Comment: What is the host Vim? Does it have anything to do with the Vim text editor? I don't use Vim...

Comment: @user996056: Do you use any vi-simulating modes?

Comment: Such as viper? No, nothing.

Comment: @user996056: did you try my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using one of the auto-completion modes and the mechanism it is using to discover possible completions causes it also search TRAMP locations. If you are using `ido` the tramp completion is controlled by variable `ido-enable-tramp-completion` and you should set that to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for  Vim references in ~/.recentf file, remove  ~/.emacs.d/.session file
and restart Emacs.